# Acumatica Error in Creating SO via WEB SERVICE

Tags: web-services, acumatica

I'm experiencing the below error when creating SO via the Acumatica Web Service. Below is the error and the sample coding.

```
PX.Data.PXException: Error #289: The button Save is disabled.

SO301000Content soSchema = context.SO301000GetSchema();            

        var commands = new List<Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SALES.Command>();
        commands.Add(new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SALES.Value
            {Value = vType, LinkedCommand = soSchema.OrderSummary.OrderType});
        commands.Add(new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SALES.Value
            {Value = vCustomer, LinkedCommand = soSchema.OrderSummary.Customer});
        commands.Add(new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SALES.Value
            {Value = TransDate.ToLongTimeString(), LinkedCommand = soSchema.OrderSummary.Date});
        commands.Add(new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SALES.Value
            {Value = TransDate.ToLongTimeString(), LinkedCommand = soSchema.OrderSummary.RequestedOn});            
        commands.Add(new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SALES.Value
            {Value = "X",LinkedCommand = soSchema.OrderSummary.Project});
        commands.Add(new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SALES.Value
            {Value = APaymentMethod,LinkedCommand = soSchema.PaymentSettings.PaymentMethod});
        commands.Add(new Acumatica_LSOne_Integration.SALES.Value
            {Value = "FROM LSOne TransactionID: " + vRecordID + " ReceiptID: " + vReceiptID,LinkedCommand = soSchema.OrderSummary.Description});            
        commands.Add(soSchema.Actions.Save);
        commands.Add(soSchema.OrderSummary.OrderNbr);

        context.SO301000Submit(commands.ToArray());
```

Comment: Can you provide a code sample which would allow us to understand what's wrong?

Comment: hi Gabriel, i edited the post and included the sample coding

Comment: Thanks, taking a look at it now

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem happens because you are setting one of the key fields, OrderType, and not indicating that you want to add a record. When doing that from the user interface, the system puts the screen on a  record, but it doesn't seem to happen automatically when getting called via web services.

You can add `soSchema.Actions.Insert` after you set the OrderType, or you can pass in a dummy OrderNbr, like : `new SO301000.Value { Value = "<NEW>", LinkedCommand = soSchema.OrderSummary.OrderNbr }`

Finally, one word of warning - you are converting the TransDate field with `ToLongTimeString()` without specifying a culture. If your client machine has different regional settings than the Acumatica server, you could end up with an error. I would recommend that you use `TransDate.ToString(System.Globalization.CultureInfo.InvariantCulture)` instead.

Answer (score 0):

Are you trying to create a single order at a time? or do you have multiple threads to do this?

Anyway try adding

`context.SO301000Clear();`

```
SO301000Content soSchema = context.SO301000GetSchema();
```

and you can add as Gabriel Mentioned..

```
SOSchema.Actions.Insert
```

after setting the OrderType. See whether this helps you or not.